# How to get resource identifier from ARN string using AWS SDK?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I have two AWS arns:

```
arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:1234567890:app/cmy-app/b473fda15a743462
arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:1234567890:targetgroup/my-app/1234567890
```

that I need to return only the `targetgroup/my-app/effe001bcbfe98af`  and `app/cmy-app/b473fda15a743462` portion. I've been trying to find a way to retrieve that through the AWS SDK but I've not been able to find the option.

I'm wondering if there is a way to do that with ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Aws::ARNParser`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/ARNParser.html):

```
str = 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:1234567890:targetgroup/my-app/1234567890'

arn = Aws::ARNParser.parse(str)
#=> #<Aws::ARN:0x00007f9b65d4b748 ...>

arn.resource
#=> "targetgroup/my-app/1234567890"
```

Comment: I just realized that the arn.resource for loadbalancers is returning loadbalancer/app/cmy-app/b473fda15a743462 instead of app/cmy-app/b473fda15a743462  is there a way to strip out loadbalancer?

Comment: @user1576738 many ways, e.g. `arn.resource.delete_prefix('loadbalancer/')`